# GroupBy propertyName first character

Tags: angular

New to angular2+, currently in angular 8 .I want to do groupBy using the property -commonName's first Character (i.e commonName[0]). I tried the below mentioned code but not working.Kindly let know how to do.

Json Data:

```
Array(5)
0: {id: 5, commonName: "Abalone Pearls", gemType: "Gemstone", categoryPath: "", categoryName: "", …}
1: {id: 3, commonName: "Abalone Shell", gemType: "Gemstone", categoryPath: "", categoryName: "", …}
2: {id: 8, commonName: "Achroite", gemType: "Gemstone", categoryPath: "", categoryName: "", …}
3: {id: 46, commonName: "Beryllonite", gemType: "Gemstone", categoryPath: "", categoryName: "", …}
4: {id: 47, commonName: "Bismuth", gemType: "Gemstone", categoryPath: "", categoryName: "", …}
```

html:

```
<section id="{{alphabet}}" class="anchor"  *ngFor="let items of details">
</section>
```

Ts:

```
export class GemopediaComponent implements OnInit {
   details:any;


  constructor(public discoverservice: DiscoverService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.discoverservice.getAllGemopedia().subscribe((data:any)=>{
      this.details = data;

      //groupBy
      const groupBy = key => array =>
      array.reduce((objectsByKeyValue, obj) => {
    const value = obj[key];
    objectsByKeyValue[value] = (objectsByKeyValue[value] || []).concat(obj);
    return objectsByKeyValue;
  }, {});

  const groupByName = groupBy('commonName.charAt(0)');
  console.log(
     groupByName(this.details)

  );
  });
  }

}
```

Comment: what is your expected output?